# why is 0 included in the interval of x so the statment (x > 0 AND x < 1) OR |x| ≤ 0 is true

Tags: logic

find the interval of x in order that this statement is true : (x > 0 AND x < 1) OR |x| ≤ 0
the answer was [0;1[

but i found ]0;1[ to be true as well since it's an OR operator . so only one statment should be true ?

Comment: "Or" means one or both can be true. "I go to the dentist or I have a cavity" is true if I go to the dentist, If I have a cavity, or if I go to the dentist and find out I have a cavity.

Comment: yea i know but i meant that if the statement is true if only one condition is true then whatever element from ]0;1[ the statement will be always true

Comment: You asked if only one statement should be true, I stated essentially no. The statement is also true for $]1/2,2/3]$, but that is not the intended answer. The question asks for **all** solutions.

Comment: In this case, both statements **can't** be true at the same time. the condition $|x| \le 0$ is true **only** when $x = 0$ (as soon as $x \neq 0$, we have $|x| > 0$). So, the statement could be simplified to, $(x > 0 \text { and } x < 1) \text{ or } x = 0$, which is a union $]0, 1[ \cup \{0\}$.

Comment: You are not being asked to find *some* conditions on $x$ which make the statement true. You are being asked to find **the** interval of *all* values of $x$ that make the statement true. That includes $x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

The aim is to find the set of all $x$ that make the statement true. If $x \in (0, 1)$, then $(x > 0)$ is true, $(x < 1)$ is true, and $|x| \leq 0$ is false, so we get:

$(x > 0 \textrm{ AND } x < 1) \textrm{ OR } (|x| \leq 0) \\
(\top \textrm{ AND } \top) \textrm{ OR } \bot \\
\top \textrm{ OR } \bot \\
\top$

where $\top$ is true, and $\bot$ is false.

But also, when $x = 0$, then $(x > 0)$ is false, $(x < 1)$ is false, and $|x| \leq 0$ is true, so the statement becomes:

$(x > 0 \textrm{ AND } x < 1) \textrm{ OR } (|x| \leq 0) \\
(\bot \textrm{ AND } \bot) \textrm{ OR } \top \\
\bot \textrm{ OR } \top \\
\top$

So $x = 0$ makes the statement true as well. That means, in order to give the full range of values, we have to include zero.